# rsync with `--links` option

Tags: rsync, symlink

The [`rsync(1)`](https://linux.die.net) man page manual says:

```
-l, --links
              When symlinks are encountered, recreate the symlink on the destination.
```

But where will the link point?

1. To the same point on the source or
2. To the same relative point on the destination?

Example:
`Dir1=/home/user/data/`
symlink at `/home/user/myproject/symlink1` pointing to `/home/user/data`

`rsync` copies the whole `/home/user` to `/media/user/flash/backup/`

What will the `/media/user/flash/backup/myproject/symlink1` point to if `rsync` was issued with `--links`? To `/home/user/data` or to `/media/user/flash/backup/data`?

And is there a way to make the second option?

Is there a difference if the symlink was created while in `/home/user/myproject` as `ln -s ../data symlink1` or as `ln -s /home/user/data /home/user/myproject/symlink1`?

Comment: You can create small test cases and check what happens (and if it matches what you want to happen).

Comment: You should think of symbolic links as if holding just a piece of text in a special way. If `ls -l filea` shows `filea -> anything`, then when filea is copied by rsync, the `ls` on the copy will give the same `-> anything`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the symlink as a text file with a path in it.  It just copies the text file.  So in your example, it will point to `/home/user/data`

To answer your subsequent question: yes there's a difference between a relative link and an absolute link.  If you want your links to be relative, you need to construct them that way. e.g.

```
/home/user/myproject/symlink1 -> ../data
```

Will be preserved the way you want.

Aside:
For a backup, you might want `-a` which implies `-l`.  It usually throws errors on an external flash drive only because most are fat32 formatted and don't support preserving all the archive options such as user and permissions.